# Google getSignedInAccountFromIntent crashing with code 10

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-signin

We are implementing Google Sign-In and authenticating with backend server as well in our mobile app.

**Developer A has the following code**:

```
val GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = "1234567890123-abcdef....apps.googleusercontent.com"

val gSignOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID)
    .requestEmail()
    .build()

val clientGoogleSignIn = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gSignOptions)

findViewById<Button>(R.id.welcome_get_started_button).setOnClickListener {
    startActivityForResult(clientGoogleSignIn.signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    try
    {
        if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
        {
            val googleAccount = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data) // FAILING LINE
               .getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            googleAccount?.let {
                log("D", "Google sign-in completed with ${it.email} and token ${it.idToken}")
                processGSignInAndStartNextActivity(it)
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e: Throwable)
    {
        log("E", "onActivityResult failed", e)
    }
}
```

In the Google project > API > Credentials page we have two client IDs:

- Web Application (the one that's in the code)
- Android (signed with SHA1 and package name)

SHA1 produced by Android Studio itself: Gradle > signingReport

**Everything is done per Google documentation, everything works.**

**Now Developer B comes in.**

He pulls the same code and uses same debug config. Same Android Studio version, same Kotlin version, same Google Play Services version. He runs the code and it consistently fails with

```
 com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:8)
```

We spent hours and tried everything - changing code, uninstalls, different AVDs, different JVM versions, nothing helped.
Eventually we decided he should create his own Android token because it made zero sense so why not.
Turns out his SHA1 generated by Android Studio was different ... As soon as he created another client ID from that SHA1 the code worked for him. Now we have 3 client IDs: Web App, Android-DevA, Android-DevB.

**Is this expected behavior that every Android developer suppose to sign application with unique SHA1 and client ID?**

I can't imagine how this works for large teams. I believe we are missing something here, so if someone more experienced can enlighten us I would appreciate it. Thank you and have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy a debug key from one of your team and provide it to all of the team members.

The debug `Keystore` should be located at `~/.android/debug.keystore`.

Or you can make another `Keystore` and share it between the developers and set it manually in `gradle`.

```
android {

    // ...

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
        }

        /*
        for release:
        release {
            storeFile file('release.keystore')
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "alias_password"
        }
        */
    }
```